# Map arrays using union or intersection to produce a third array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I am trying to solve a problem in Angular 7, where i need to write a function that takes two array of objects, in this case, the first one and the second one, and returns the third array.

The third array is very similar to the first array, but the value of the `count` key in the `children` array is dependent on whether there are any `children` in the second array or if present, reflect the value of `count` in that object. Is there an array map function in angular that can solve this?

**First array:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Category 1",
        "value": "Vegetables",
        "children": [
            {"name": "Carrots", "value": "Carrots", "count": 2},
            {"name": "Peas", "value": "Peas", "count": 1}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Category 2",
        "value": "Fruits",
        "children": [
            {"name": "Apples", "value": "Apples", "count": 10},
            {"name": "Bananas", "value": "Bananas", "count": 5}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Category 3",
        "value": "Desserts",
        "children": [
            {"name": "Ice Cream", "value": "IceCream", "count": 3},
            {"name": "Cakes", "value": "Cakes", "count": 3}
        ]
    }
]
```

**Second array**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Category 1",
        "value": "Vegetables",
        "children": [
            {"name": "Peas", "value": "Peas", "count": 1}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Category 2",
        "value": "Fruits",
        "children": [
            {"name": "Apples", "value": "Apples", "count": 3},
            {"name": "Bananas", "value": "Bananas", "count": 2}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Category 3",
        "value": "Desserts",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

**Third array**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Category 1",
        "value": "Vegetables",
        "children": [
            {"name": "Carrots", "value": "Carrots", "count": 0},
            {"name": "Peas", "value": "Peas", "count": 1}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Category 2",
        "value": "Fruits",
        "children": [
            {"name": "Apples", "value": "Apples", "count": 3},
            {"name": "Bananas", "value": "Bananas", "count": 2}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Category 3",
        "value": "Desserts",
        "children": [
            {"name": "Ice Cream", "value": "IceCream", "count": 0},
            {"name": "Cakes", "value": "Cakes", "count": 0}
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here idea is

- First change the second array to object so it becomes easier to find values on it
- Now loop through array1 and take the respective children from array2
- Loop on children of array1 and change value according to children from array2

```js
const arr1 = [{"name":"Category 1","value":"Vegetables","children":[{"name":"Carrots","value":"Carrots","count":2},{"name":"Peas","value":"Peas","count":1}]},{"name":"Category 2","value":"Fruits","children":[{"name":"Apples","value":"Apples","count":10},{"name":"Bananas","value":"Bananas","count":5}]},{"name":"Category 3","value":"Desserts","children":[{"name":"Ice Cream","value":"IceCream","count":3},{"name":"Cakes","value":"Cakes","count":3}]}];
const arr2 = [{"name":"Category 1","value":"Vegetables","children":[{"name":"Peas","value":"Peas","count":1}]},{"name":"Category 2","value":"Fruits","children":[{"name":"Apples","value":"Apples","count":3},{"name":"Bananas","value":"Bananas","count":2}]},{"name":"Category 3","value":"Desserts","children":[]}];
 
let arr2Obj = Object.fromEntries(arr2.map(val => [val.name, val]))

const res = arr1.map(({ name, value, children }) => {
  let arr2Children = ( arr2Obj[name] || {} ).children
  let childrenObj = Object.fromEntries(arr2Children.map(val => [val.name,val]))
  let newChildren = children.map( val => {
    let count = (childrenObj[val.name] || {}).count || 0
    return {...val,count}
  })
  return {name,value,children:newChildren}
});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

**P.S:-** If your array1 and array2 are always in sorted manner than you need not to change it object and you can directly access using index, same for the children

```js
const arr1 = [{"name":"Category 1","value":"Vegetables","children":[{"name":"Carrots","value":"Carrots","count":2},{"name":"Peas","value":"Peas","count":1}]},{"name":"Category 2","value":"Fruits","children":[{"name":"Apples","value":"Apples","count":10},{"name":"Bananas","value":"Bananas","count":5}]},{"name":"Category 3","value":"Desserts","children":[{"name":"Ice Cream","value":"IceCream","count":3},{"name":"Cakes","value":"Cakes","count":3}]}];
const arr2 = [{"name":"Category 1","value":"Vegetables","children":[{"name":"Peas","value":"Peas","count":1}]},{"name":"Category 2","value":"Fruits","children":[{"name":"Apples","value":"Apples","count":3},{"name":"Bananas","value":"Bananas","count":2}]},{"name":"Category 3","value":"Desserts","children":[]}];

let createObject = (arr) => arr.reduce((op,[key,value])=>{
  op[key] = value
  return op
},{})

let arr2Obj = createObject(arr2.map(val => [val.name, val]))

const res = arr1.map(({ name, value, children }) => {
  let arr2Children = ( arr2Obj[name] || {} ).children
  let childrenObj = createObject(arr2Children.map(val => [val.name,val]))
  let newChildren = children.map( val => {
    let count = (childrenObj[val.name] || {}).count || 0
    return {...val,count}
  })
  return {name,value,children:newChildren}
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: hmm. I am getting an error that "fromEntries" does not exist on type ObjectConstructor.

Comment: @Jake you can use polfill for that, let me update it with a version which doesn't uses a Object.fromEntries

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quite simply with `map` and `find`, then `reduce` the array afterwards.

```js
const arr1 = [{"name":"Category 1","value":"Vegetables","children":[{"name":"Carrots","value":"Carrots","count":2},{"name":"Peas","value":"Peas","count":1}]},{"name":"Category 2","value":"Fruits","children":[{"name":"Apples","value":"Apples","count":10},{"name":"Bananas","value":"Bananas","count":5}]},{"name":"Category 3","value":"Desserts","children":[{"name":"Ice Cream","value":"IceCream","count":3},{"name":"Cakes","value":"Cakes","count":3}]}];
const arr2 = [{"name":"Category 1","value":"Vegetables","children":[{"name":"Peas","value":"Peas","count":1}]},{"name":"Category 2","value":"Fruits","children":[{"name":"Apples","value":"Apples","count":3},{"name":"Bananas","value":"Bananas","count":2}]},{"name":"Category 3","value":"Desserts","children":[]}];
const res = arr1.map(({ name, value, children }) => {
  let found = arr2.find(({ name: n, value: v }) => n == name && v == value);
  if (found) children = children.concat(found.children).reduce((a, c) => {
    let f = a.findIndex(({ name: n }) => n == c.name);
    if (f > -1) a[f].count += c.count;
    else a.push(c);
    return a;
  }, []);
  return { name, value, children };
});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: I think this is adding duplicate children in the resultant array, rather than updating the value of the `count` key. Ex: You can see that in your snippet solution, the `children` of the resultant array for `Category 1` now has 2 objects with `Peas` in it, each with a `count: 1` rather than having one with `count: 2`

Comment: Fixed @Jake, any better?

Comment: Sorry, there are no duplicates now, which is good, but the counts don't match the third array in the post. :(

Comment: Erm...what happened to the 3 cakes and ice creams in the first array? Why did they go?

Comment: Since the second array, doesn't have them, they should be there in the third array, but their count should be 0.